# Failed run a user's alias inside bash CLI

Tags: command-line, bash

How can run a user's alias

```
$ grab 'man'
```

but as to do in a CLI

```
$ bash -c "grab 'man'"
bash: line 1: grab: command not found
```

Please show the fixing way

Comment: where is the user's alias defined?  If it isn't in their `.bashrc` it won't be available in `bash` calls.  And if they are not defined in your current session you can't use them.  (every alias is session-only and has to be reloaded on each Bash session)

Comment: `bash -c` invokes a non-interactive shell iirc, so aliases won't be expanded and (at least with the default .bashrc) their definitions will likely be skipped if they follow the "If not running interactively, don't do anything" check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias is for interactive use only. It do not take effect when you attempt to run them from the non-interactive shell you initiate with the `bash -c` command.

There are two approaches if you want a custom command to be available in a non-interactive shell.

**Alternative 1. Create a script in a directory in the PATH**

For example, create a script `~/.local/bin/grab` that executes the long command. The directory `~/.local/bin/` is automatically included in the `PATH` when it exists, so you can run this script by simply typing `grab`. It is also available in a non-interactive subshell.

**Alternative 2. Create a function in your shell's profile config file**

For `bash`, you would define a function in your `~/.profile` configuration file:

```
grab () {
<actual code>
}
```

`~/.profile` is read when you log in. From now on, `grab` will be like an internal bash command, and can be accessed by simply typing `grab`.  It is also available in a non-interactive subshell.